# Limit of a sequence in a series form

Tags: sequences-and-series

For every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let
$$
x_k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^{2k}.
$$
Calculate the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k$.

Comment: Isn't it just 0? The term $(1 - \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{4n^2})$ is less than $1$ for all $n$; pick any $\lambda$ between the minimum value this attains and 1; now your sum is positive but less than $\lambda^{2k}$ times the sum of $1/n^2$; since this sum converges, the limit as $k$ goes to $\infty$ is 0.

Comment: I mean maximum, there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:** By the dominated convergence theorem, we may switch the order of the limit and the sum, so we see that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k =0.$$

**Solution 2:** Notice the terms are always bounded above by $\frac{1}{n^2}$.  Let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $N$ such that $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon.$$  Then choose $k$ so large that $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2N}\right)^{2k}\leq \frac{\epsilon}{N}.$$  It then follows that $| x_k| \leq 2\epsilon,$ and the same inequality holds for  all $j\geq k$.  Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary the proof is finished.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Since $\displaystyle\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)<1\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, it follows that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)^{2k}=0$.

Comment: you mean $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=0$

Comment: @Sam, naturally, you're right

Comment: You still have to justify switching the order of the limit and the sum.  I feel this hint misses the point of the question.

Comment: @Eric Au contraire, I feel that this hint can be of help to the OP. Your answer, on the other hand, whilst correct, is in my opinion overly intricate for a question at this level (I'd guess it's taken from a 1st year undergrad math book).